# Why do Amenadiel and Lucifer speak with different accents?

Tags: lucifer

Ameanadiel and Lucifer are both angels in origin and were both born (or created or however angels come into being) in the silver city and they both have the same "parents" if parenthood has any meaning for a celestial being). In short they are brothers from the same family and come from the same environment.

But they don't talk the same way or with the same accents as you might expect. Why not? Is there an in-universe explanation (obviously, out of universe, all baddies have to speak with English accents: that's the rule)?

Comment: I haven't watched Lucifer, but is there any particular reason why they *shouldn't* speak in different accents?

Comment: It's not like they're actually from any *country*...if anything they should be speaking Aramaic!

Comment: @Paulie_D Technically, since they precede the Aramaic period by a few thousand years, they'd be more likely to speak ancient Sumerian or ancient Chinese.  Or whatever they had before then...

Answer (score 6):

Lucifer flatly says that he "can speak any human language" (on the contrast, Amanadiel can read almost any human language). But in any case, they are both not humans and spent last few millennia in vast different places, so even if they started with same accent, it could change over time.

During his interview, Tom Ellis (playing Lucifer) said that he wanted his accent to "make it aristocratic with a bit of rock and roll, using “Noël Coward and Mick Jagger’s love child as the starting point.” In the end he accomplished something quite similar to [Received Pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)

This would match nicely Lucifer as a character: charismatic, proud, educated and sexy.

On the contrast, Amanadiel is humble - he doesn't look to impress people but to follow the will of his Father - hence he has less distinct American accent.